# Putting for loop inside a function

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to stop my for loop when it equals a certain input, I was able to achieve this outside of a function. For example, lets say I set the input variable to 'not leak', I want the loop to stop when the array hits 'not' and adds it to the keyword variable which is set to 'leak' to output 'not leak'. However, when I tried inserting my loop into a function it stopped working as expected and would give each result until the input variable equaled the text variable (which I don't want it to do). For example, it would output 'no leak', 'not leak' and that is where it would stop, when I just want it to output 'not leak'

I have tried various formats for the functions, such as setting the function as a variable, giving the function parameters, and putting the variables inside and outside the function with zero progress. It seems the the break if statement does not work as expected once it is inserted into a function. Any idea why and how to fix this?

Below is how it looks inside a function.

```js
function negKeyword() {
 
var keyword = 'leak'; 
var input = 'not leak'; 
var text = ''; 
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked', '']; 
 
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text == input) { break; } 
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 console.log(text);
 
 }
 
}

negKeyword();
```

Below is how it looks outside a function

```js
var keyword = 'leak'; 

var input = 'no leak'; 

var text = ""; 

var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked', '']; 

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text===input) {break;}
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 
}

console.log(text);
```

Comment: It's doing the exact same thing inside and outside of any function. You just have the `console.log` in different places. Perhaps you should indent your code properly so that you can see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using console.log inside the loop. The function below matched both the inside one and outside one.

```js
function negKeyword() {
 
var keyword = 'leak'; 
var input = 'not leak'; 
var text = ''; 
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked', '']; 
 
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text == input) { break; } 
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 
 
 }
        console.log(text);//Place this here ( outside the for loop )
 
}

negKeyword();
```

Comment: The closing bracket and `console.log` shouldn't be indented. I feel that it's the real cause of grief here.

Comment: I figured it would be something simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log is inside the loop.

```js
function negKeyword() {
 
var keyword = 'leak'; 
var input = 'not leak'; 
var text = ''; 
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked', '']; 
 
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text == input) { break; } 
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 }
 return text;
}

console.log( negKeyword() );
```